# .net webapp read Oracle data error

Tags: .net, windows, oracle, iis-6

i have a app run on iis6 using c# to read Oracle long type data,when the data field is too long(over 9000 characters),the DataSet result will included some messy code in my bussiness data.like below:

---

... ...
VR-P62 0646/22 0646/21 0646/23 0646/24`aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG.cs,C:\WINDOW\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.5.0727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG.csproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.N6`  0646/22 0646/21 0646/23 0646/24
... ...

any suggestion ? thanks very much !